# How to push without accepting changes to github

Tags: github, command-line, push, pull

What command do I use to push my code to github through VSCode command line? It is making me pull first, but I don't want to accept any incoming changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's happening because your current branch (assuming it is `main` or `master`) is outdated and wants to update itself first.

There are some ways you can do this:

1. Using Git in the command line (**recommended, easiest way**).
2. Using Visual Studio Code UI.

### Using Git in the command line

Say, the current branch you're working on is named `updates`.
We can use the following command to push to GitHub:

```sh
git push origin updates:updates
```

That will push your changes remotely (GitHub).
You might wonder why `updates:updates`:

The first one is the name of the local branch, the second one is the name of the remote branch.
After that, your changes will be pushed to GitHub in the branch `updates`.

If your branch isn't available remotely yet, it will create a new branch named `updates` with the same commits and changes in the local branch `updates`.

### Using Visual Studio Code UI

First make sure you're on the correct local branch. You can change branches by clicking on the name of the current branch you're on on the bottom at the left.
Next, go to the Source Control (`Ctrl+Shift+G`), then click on the `...`, then `Push`.

Your changes will be pushed to GitHub now with the same local branch name.
Hope this answer is useful to you.

Comment: Hello, I am working on my own branch. The issue is someone pushed code into my branch after I started working on something, but I don't need that person's code anymore. I am trying to push and override that persons changes.

Comment: You can revert the changes they made in a PR, and then push your changes. Or, make another branch removing those person's changes and implementing your changes, compare branches and then merge.